# How to install ArangoDb in DCOS with customized options in arangod.conf file

Tags: arangodb, dcos

I've currently installed ArangoDb within DCOS using the DCOS installer. However i would like to modify the arangod.conf file with some logging configurations based on this link : https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/arangodb-server/options/#--loglevel

Please can you let me know, if there are any ways to override the configuration in arangod.conf, while installing using DCOS.

Answer (score 2):

All options specified in the config file may also be specified using the command line.

The command line can be adjusted using the UI:

https://github.com/mesosphere/universe/blob/version-3.x/repo/packages/A/arangodb3/5/config.json#L203

Another possiblity would be to derive a custom container from the official arangodb-mesos package and include the changes there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one doubt in this option : "arangodb-additional-coordinator-args", how to specify multiple  parameters. Basically what are the delimiters which are accepted to include multiple parameters.

Comment: I tried this command - "--arangodb-additional-coordinator-args=log.level:requests=info"  as per your suggestion on the existing ArangoDB instance which is  running, but it didn't work. Please can you let me know the right syntax